# Google Maps v3 api in routed view doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

Hi guys i have problems trying to run a google map example into a routed view, map is not displayed and no errors are displayed, i read some thing about initialize in a directive, i don't know how to do it, any help will be very apreciated:

**app.conf**

```
app.controller( 'viewCtrl', function( $http, $location ) {
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
} );
```

In my **view** i have:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Have you set width and height on #map-canvas element? Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/1mdp3jxe/2/

Comment: It work fine in main html, the problem is when i try to use that div into a routed view, map just doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked into my view adding a size to div:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
```

Sry for this questión and hoppe thiscan help to others

Comment: Thanks for your response, I stop using AngularJS to do it with Android Studio